# create-react-app jest encountered unexpected token {

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I'm developing a React app with a QR-scanner in it with `create-react-app`.
I've added the module `react-qr-reader` which in turn uses the modules `webrtc-adapter`.

It all works great, until I run `yarn test`. Then it shows me this error:
[image]

I've already ejected the project so I can use `transformIgnorePatterns` and added `node_modules/webrtc-adapter` to the array, but that still results in the same error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you build a sample app and paste link here ?

Comment: It's nothing more than the following: `npx create-react-app myProject` -> `yarn add react-qr-reader` -> `import QRReader from 'react-qr-reader';` in src/App.js -> `yarn test`

Comment: Demo repo: https://github.com/CherryNerd/CRA-qr-reader

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want to eject from Create-React-App you can use the CLI in your package.json to override 'transformIgnorePatterns'.

Reference - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2537#issuecomment-390341713

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!your-module-name)/\"",
  },
```

Answer (score 7):

It's because of de ES6 syntax in a package into node_modules, you need to config the "transformIgnorePatterns" to transform this package.

The issue on Jest: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2081

How to configure:  http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#transformignorepatterns-customization

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(react-qr-reader)/)"
]
```

if this doesn't work, use the babel.config.js with this configuration (is important the file ".js", this configuration don't work in ".babelrc" file):

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": "commonjs",
        "debug": false
      }
    ],
    /// your presets
  ],
  plugins: [
    //... your plugins
  ]
};
```