# How to fix 'window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function' when testing mapbox-gl in React?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme, mapbox-gl-js

I'm testing React component with Mapbox, material-ui and custom styles. I use Jest + Enzyme for testing.

I have problem: 'window.URL.createObjectURL is not a function'. I read similar questions:
[github.com/uber/react-map-gl/issues/210](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/issues/210)
[github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3436](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3436)
[github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js-mock](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js-mock)

and tried to add something but without success. Please, fix the issue.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-enzyme-mapbox-test-qobf0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had faced exactly same issue with my jest test suite. After some trial and searching, I was able to mock the `createObjectURL` method.

In `jest.stub.js` file, I put this config:

```js
if (typeof window.URL.createObjectURL === 'undefined') {
  window.URL.createObjectURL = () => {
    // Do nothing
    // Mock this function for mapbox-gl to work
  };
}
```

Then, in `jest.config.js` file, I added a reference to the stub file

```js
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/tests/jest.stub.js',
  ],
```

Note: make sure you get the path right in setupFile defintion.

Comment: Thanks, but how to find jest.stub.js and jest.config.js [in my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-enzyme-mapbox-test-qobf0)?

Comment: Finally solution :) May universe server you well, sir.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue running tests using the library Plotly.js with React and Jest.

My solution was to add a file `src/setupTests.js` with a mock for the createObjectURL function `window.URL.createObjectURL = function() {};`

Answer (score 1):

I also was using React with Mapbox-gl and @Pablo Jurado's solution worked perfectly.

Just pasted `window.URL.createObjectURL = function() {};`

to `src/setupTest.js` file

and also modified npm test script to:

`"scripts": { "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!your-module-name)/\"", },`

based on
[this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57299219/7958826)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add package: mapbox-gl-js-mock
2. add  require("mapbox-gl-js-mock"); before jest.mock(

   import React from 'react';
       import { createShallow } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';

   ```
   import App from './App';
   require("mapbox-gl-js-mock");

   jest.mock('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl', () => ({
     App: () => ({}),
   }));

   describe('<App />', () => {
     let shallow;

     beforeEach(() => {
       shallow = createShallow({ dive: true });
     });

     it('renders without crashing', () => {
       const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
       expect(wrapper.find('.MapBox')).toExist();
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. [CodeSandbox with your changes](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-enzyme-mapbox-test-qobf0)