# Testing React/Typescript components with Jest module errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I am receiving the error `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` when running a simple test on a React/Typescript component and not sure the best way of using modules in a React/Typescript project with Babel, webpack, and jest.

Here is my babel.config.js :

```
const isTest = String(process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'test'
const isProd = String(process.env.NODE_ENV) === 'production'

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { modules: isTest ? 'commonjs' : false }], 
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
};
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
  "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
  "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
  "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
  ],
  "transform": {
  "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
  
  }
```

Here is the simple test I am trying to run:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import AppRouter from '../router'

test('it works!', () => {
    render(<AppRouter />)
})
```

Please help!

**Solution**

Be sure to check your testRegex in your jest.config.js file and the testEnvironment is set correctly with `testEnvironment: "jsdom"` if you are using ES6 modules for testing.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the test where are you getting the error, because seeing the code will help to answer more appropriately.

Comment: @BhaveshDaswani For sure, just added it to the post.

Comment: Do you have a setupTests.ts file? in the main directory?  https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom

Comment: @ColinHale Yes, the only code that is in there is this: ```import "@testing-library/jest-dom"```

Comment: Im not sure what is going on. Is the file location outside of the scope? Here is an example of using testing library on a codesandbox, Maybe try to reproduce it here.
One thing you need to consider with Routers is the you will need to surround the component you are testing with a BrowserRouter.: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-9ik86?file=/src/__tests__/hello.js

Comment: Did you try adding "type": "module" to your package.json? It should enforce ESM when you run your test.

Comment: Yes - no change with that @PatriceThimothee

Comment: Jest throws a ```Jest encountered an unexpected token``` error and says that it failed to parse a file. This happens when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JS syntax or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax. I believe it may have to do with how Babel is configured to interpret the files but still not sure. @ColinHale

Comment: Maybe config related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921019/jest-test-fails-with-unexpected-token-expected

Comment: What changed that caused Jest to throw a different Error? That unexpected token thing usually is because of an npm package in my experiend with jext. May need to an an ignorePatterns seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493322/create-react-app-jest-encountered-unexpected-token.

I still think it has to do with the test directory. Try and put a test in a different part of the project out of the test directory. see if it works there. You may need to change   "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)", to like _tests_ or tests or its not pointing at the write spot?

Comment: There was no other error. That error shows up and then 10 lines below in terminal it says the module error. BUT, I think it's working after changing my testRegex to ```'(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.js?$'```. Now, I am not exactly sure this works because the test gives me a Missing Semicolon error on the .tsx component I am testing when there is no error there. Jest is pointing to type Props with the carrot in between type and Props when no semicolon goes there. But if I run a regular test, it works. And thank you for the share @PatriceThimothee